# Concatenating undefined variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, concatenation

If I have several variables, e.g.

```
var t1 = "123";
var t2 = null;
var t3 = "456";
```

And I want to concatenate t1 + t2 + t3, is there a fixed output for such a string or is the result dependent upon different Javascript engines?

Comment: What do you mean by _is there a fixed output for such a string_? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @elclanrs: For example, when I'm using the Chrome JS Debugger, I've found that the output actually is "123undefined456".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will return the same output regardless of browsers. If any, its only the `null` part that may be different (unlikely)

In this case it will be `"123null456"`

To offset any inconsistencies regarding how a `null` value of converted to a string by different browsers, you can use:

```
function concatAll() {
   var s = '';
   for(var x in arguments) {
       s += arguments[x] == null ? 'null' : arguments[x];
   }
   return s;
}

var t1 = "123";
var t2 = null;
var t3 = "456";

concatAll(t1, t2, t3); // will return "123null456"
```

Answer (score 11):

It will be the same in all browsers/engines. You can do it like this (Assuming t1, t2, t3 will be strings always)

```
var t1 = "123";
var t2 = null;
var t3 = "456";

var result = (t1 || "") + (t2 || "") + (t3 || ""); // Logical OR `||` to avoid null/undefined.
```

Result will be `123456`

Comment: Note that if you are using literal numbers instead of strings, `0` will be skipped. But then again, if you're concatenating numbers with just `+` you've got bigger problems.